# Overflow of .btn object revealed for a second when hover-off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to sort out how to keep the border-radius property of a circular button to remain when hovering over and away from it. So far I've been able to figure out how to have the button keep the border-radius property by setting the overflow property to hidden, but for some reason the button would not stop revealing the overflow when I move the mouse off the button, showing it to be a square for a fraction of a second before taking on the border-radius property. Here is the CSS code attached to this particular button.

```
.container-for-atbd_author_avatar .btn {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 85%;
  left: 85%;
}


.container-for-atbd_author_avatar .btn:hover {
  /* border-radius: 50%!important; */
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide html and put everthing into a snippet so we could see it in action? Or a codepen link.

Comment: [mre] or it didn’t happen.

Comment: don't add the overflow property when user hover on it. but put it inside .container-for-atbd_author_avatar .btn {} this class.